# JSON Parsing with NSDictionary and finding value by key

Tags: ios, json, nsdictionary

I have a simple `NSDictionary` that I am trying to populate with data from an external site via JSON that is returned.  The JSON that is returned is fine but I am haveing trouble getting actual data for a specific key.

Here is the JSON data printed to the console.

This is my JSON data:

```
(
        {
        CategoryID = 12345;
        CategoryName = "Baked Goods";
    },
        {
        CategoryID = 12346;
        CategoryName = Beverages;
    },
        {
        CategoryID = 12347;
        CategoryName = "Dried Goods";
    },
        {
        CategoryID = 12348;
        CategoryName = "Frozen Fruit & Vegetables";
    },
        {
        CategoryID = 12349;
        CategoryName = Fruit;
    },
        {
        CategoryID = 12340;
        CategoryName = "Purees & Soups";
    },
        {
        CategoryID = 12341;
        CategoryName = Salad;
    },
        {
        CategoryID = 12342;
        CategoryName = "Snack Items";
    },
        {
        CategoryID = 12343;
        CategoryName = Vegetables;
    }
)
```

The error I am getting is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray
>   enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x6884000'

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    NSError *error = nil;
    // Get the JSON data from the website
    NSDictionary *categories = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data  options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    if (categories.count > 0){
        NSLog(@"This is my JSON data %@", categories);

        [categories enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: ^(__strong id key, __strong id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"Key = %@, Object For Key = %@", key, obj); }];
}
```

I'm not sure why this is happening but I'm sure it's something simple like I am using the incorrect object or something.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to work it out from the error. It tells you everything you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` is returning an NSArray not an NSDictionary. `'-[__NSCFArray enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:]` is the key part of the error message. It tells you that you are calling `-enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:` on an array.

---

For this case, you could use `-enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` instead.

If you are not sure wether a NSArray or an NSDictionary will be returned, you can use `-isKindOf:`

```
id result = [NSJSONSerialization …];
if ([result isKindOf:[NSArray class]]) {
    NSArray *categories = result;
    // Process the array
} else if ([result isKindOf:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    NSDictionary *categories = result;
    // Process the dictionary
}
```

---

From [enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:)

> Executes a given block using each object in the array, starting with the first object and continuing through the array to the last object.
>
> - (void)enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))block

So it should be called as such

```
[categories enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"index = %d, Object For Key = %@", idx, obj);
}];
```

A quick read of the documentation really can save you lots of frustration.

Comment: Thanks, I have seen the isKindOfClass before and that certainly helps. I placed the code inside the NSArray and I am getting a different error now...

Comment: Thanks, I have seen the isKindOfClass before and that certainly helps. I placed the code inside the NSArray and I am getting a different error now... Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void(^)(__strong id, __strong id, BOOL *)' to a parameter of type 'void(^)(__strong id, NSUInteger, BOOL *)'  I understand there is a problem with the second parameter but what unsigned integer value does it expect?  I am just trying to iterate the array for all keys and their associated values.

Comment: Thanks, I'm completely new to iOS.  I find the documentation to be a bit of a black hole.  Once I understand why something isn't working then I see the use of the documentation....anyway, thanks.